# Mapping intervals exponentially

Tags: functions

I have two intervals: $X=[A,B]$ and $X'=[C,D]$.

If I'd like to map $X$ to $X'$, I usually use this equation:

$$f(t)= \frac{D-C} {B-A} t + \frac{(BC - AD)} {B-A}$$

where $t$ is the time.

However this is linear mapping. I would like to do the mapping exponentially. Could someone help me in this?

I appreciate you help.

Comment: I just reformatted your equations. You might want to check them over to make sure I didn't screw them up somehow. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "exponentially" you mean you want a map of the form $f(t)=ke^{rt}$. So we get the equations $$C=ke^{Ar},\qquad D=ke^{Br}$$ Then $$C/D=e^{(A-B)r}$$ so $$r={\log C-\log D\over A-B}\tag1$$ and $k=Ce^{-kr}$ where $r$ is given by (1).

EDIT: As Ross points out in the comments, that was meant to be $k=Ce^{-Ar}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how do I calculate f(t) from A B C and D?

Comment: How is k = Ce (pow) -kr

Comment: @user951793:  I believe $k=Ce^{-Ar}$  Once you have $k,r$ you have everything you need for $f(t)$

Comment: @RossMillikan I tried the equation with calculating k value as you suggested, but I get the following over the time:


Scale:Infinity
Scale:Infinity
Scale:Infinity


My test case is:
A = 100;
B = 3100;
C = 0;
D = 400;

Comment: @user951793:  that is because you are trying to take the log of zero with $C=0$.  The way $f(t)$ is defined, it cannot be zero.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan. Changing C to 1 made it work.